# Showing that a function is continuous when restriction on closed set is

Tags: general-topology

Another question that I completely botched and scored 0 points on. The method I tried to use didn't even use all of the assumptions because I had no clue. The assignment goes as follows.


$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function with $X$ and $Y$ being topological spaces. Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of closed subsets in $X$ and we have that $\cup_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A=X$. Let $f\vert_A:A\rightarrow Y$ be the restriction from $A$ to $Y$ that is cnt. for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Suppose for every open neighbourhood $U$ of $x\in X$ that $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for only finitely many $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Show that $f$ is continuous.